# Solving for $\log^*n$

Tags: logarithms

I know the iterative logarithm can only produce 1 of 6 numbers. However, I don't really understand how to solve. Can someone please explain how to solve $\log^*n$ where $n$ is any number, lets say like 100. Would there be any difference for $\lg^*n$?

Comment: What is the base of this logarith??

Comment: `log` = base 10; `lg` = base 2

Comment: It is absolutely false that the iterative logarithm can only produce one of $6$ numbers.  You just need to start with a large enough number.  Numbers that large are rarely encountered unless you are working problems like this, but most naturals are even larger.  There are only finitely many naturals $n$ with $\log^* n \le 6$ but infinitely many larger than that.  One example would be $10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10^{10}}}}}}}$  You can continue the stack as high as you want to get the $\log^*$ as large as you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose we'd like to solve $\log^*100$ with a base-10 logarithm. $\log100=2$, which is greater than 1, but $\log\log100$ is less than 1. Thus $\log^*100=2$.

For $\lg^*100$ (base 2) we have
$$\lg100=6.644$$
$$\lg\lg100=2.732$$
$$\lg\lg\lg100=1.450$$
$$\lg\lg\lg\lg100=0.536$$
so $\lg^*100=4$.

These functions sometimes come up in analysis of algorithms, and they grow very slowly. While they can theoretically take on any value, for all practical values of $x$ even $\lg^*x$ is always five or less.

Comment: oooh, so it's basically the number of iterations until the answer is less than 1?

Comment: @Adjit _Yes..._

Answer (score 1):

There I a huge difference between $\log_{10} n$ and $\log_2 n$.Let the first value be $x$ and the second be $y$.Then $n=2^x$ and $n=10^y$.That's why The value of $x$ and $y$ after different.
To solve it you have to write $n$ as a power of $10$.
Examples:1) $\log_{10} 100=\log_{10} 10^2=2$

2)$\log_{10} 200=\log_{10} 100 + \log_{10} 2=2+\log2$

Comment: so how would I solve for log star n?

Comment: @Adjit It is done in the question.And if you need more explanation then tell me.And read the theorems of logarithm properly

Answer (score 1):

In fact, $Log^{*}(n)$ is a recursive function.
$$Log^{*}(n) = \begin{cases}Log^{*}(log(n))+1 \qquad if\text{ } log(n)\geq 1\\ 0\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{ }\text{ } if\text{ }log(n)< 1\end{cases}$$